gRPC client connection pooling in Java
I am implementing a gRPC client that needs to make a lot of requests/sec to another gRPC server. So far I have got this
ManagedChannel managedChannel = Grpc.newChannelBuilderForAddress("localhost", 20503, channelCredentials)
        .executor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20))
        .build();

As you can see, the threadpool I have specificed is 20. Does it mean that this channel will only allow 20 concurrent requests at a given instant? Is this the right way of connection pooling in gRPC java? If I did not specify any thread pool, then does it mean the channel can make only ONE RPC call at a time?
Thank you.

Pending streams (rpcsp) are submitted to the executor as Runnable tasks regardless of the executor thread pool size. Because the rpcs will involve IO operations on the network, even a thread pool of size 1 can multiplex threads executing different rpcs whenever a thread waits for IO.
